# Is there a .NET video player that works under AnyCPU?

Tags: .net, video, com, media-player

The WindowsMediaPlayer has to be added as either the 32-bit COM object or the 64-bit COM object. There does not appear to be any way to include it so it runs under both configurations.

Is there a player out there that will run in both 32-bit and 64-bit? We must do both because we're an Office AddIn and Office 2010 has both a 32-bit and 64-bit version so we're called in the matching bit-ness.

thanks - dave

Comment: Great question! As i know 64-bit office supports 32-bit addins... You can support one add-in for that - x86... Other solution is to create separe library with interfaces and 2 libraries with their implementations. And load via reflection from add-in that